# Captcha image not showing in my asp.net mvc application

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```html
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
<div>                                                       
   <div>
   @Html.Captcha(4)
   <p class="Error"> @ViewBag.ErrMessage </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using simple captcha in login page but when application loads first login page captcha image not showing

Answer (score 0):

You need to be registered, and have some specific code that you can get by going to the link below:

[Recaptcha Solution here!](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create)

Comment: Please tell me where and how to registered for captcha instead of recaptcha

Comment: Captcha and reCaptcha are the same thing basically but if you really want captcha here it is:

https://captchas.net/registration/